# Gauging interest in a potential academia-focused product

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate for the Academia.SE to gauge interest of the community in a potential product (service), focused on the academic market? If so, what is the best way to do that: *asking a question* or *starting a poll* (not sure, if this feature exists on this site or on SE, in general)? Note that this is not about advertising existing commercial offering, but rather about *validating idea* via feedback.

Comment: May I know how different this would be from "shopping questions" that SE wants us to avoid?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: Typically, "shopping questions" on SE are frown upon due to being open-ended, their lifetime issues and attracting spam (see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/263279)). My "validating idea" question would be different as it would not present any of those issues. However, based on the community feedback and other considerations, I have decided not to pursue this route on SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If so, what is the best way to do that: *asking a question* or *starting a poll* […]?

Stack Exchange has no poll feature and poll-like questions (e.g., “What do you think about …?”, “Would you use …?”, “What is your experience with …?”) are not welcome.

What you can do is to discuss the idea in chat or host a poll externally and advertise it on Meta, in chat or even the community ads (if it gets upvoted).

Comment: Thank you for clarification and suggestion.